# Как задать путь к картинке java android

Tags: java, android, изображения

Нужно вывести на экран картинку из файла. В проекте есть папка `img`, в ней лежат картинки. Переменная `fname` получается равной `/data/data/com.example.achess/files/img/peshka-w.png`
Но объект `bitmap` создается равным `null` (не находит такой путь). Подскажите где косяк?

```
 String fname=new File(context.getFilesDir()+"/img/"+Figures[i].patch).getAbsolutePath();
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fname);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 50, 50, paint);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если Вы хотите использовать assets, то просто:

1. Переместите картинку в assets
2. `InputStream ims = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/assets/peshka-w.png");`
3. отобразите картинку `imageView.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromStream(ims, null));`

Если Вам необходимо получить именно Bitmap попробуйте использовать

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(ims);
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `Context.getFilesDir()` - не всегда показывает на `/data/data/[package]/files` - это можно переопределить и к тому же иногда зависит от версии оси
2. То что файл лежит в проекте, не означает что он также и будет лежать на устройстве. Возьмите `adb shell` и наберите `cd /data/data/[package]/files` - скорее всего файла там нет
3. Обычное каталог, куда показывает `Context.getFilesDir()` используется не для того, чтобы туда класть ресурсы, а чтобы туда складывать файлы, которые аппа генерирует по ходу действия.

Лучше положите файл в `assets` и читайте оттуда - не грейте голову.

Comment: Спасибо, пробую. Положила все картинки в assets.       fname = "file:///android_asset/peshka-w.png";  Опять не видит этот путь. Что же делать?

Comment: https://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/10/02/store-and-use-files-in-assets/

Answer (score 1):

Всем спасибо в итоге получился работающий код:

```
public void Draw_Figures(Paint paint, Canvas canvas) {
        try {

              int x1;
              int y1;            
              Bitmap bitmap;

              BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
              options.outHeight = cell_height;
              options.outWidth = cell_width;
              for(int i = 0; i <= 32; i++)
              {                                
                    x1 = (int) (Figures[i].x *cell_width)-cell_width;
                    y1 = (int) (8*cell_height-(Figures[i].y)*cell_height);
                    InputStream ims = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/assets/"+Figures[i].patch);
                    bitmap  = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(ims, null, options);
                    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, x1, y1, paint);
              }     
         } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
         } 
    }
```